# How to make a DXGrid control properly update when DataBound

Tags: wpf, mvvm, devexpress

When the list underlying my databound DXGrid is updated, the scrollbar of the grid updates but the body of the grid does not, at least not right away. As soon as I click on the grid scrollbar, the body does refresh.

To illustrate - here is my application in the initial state:

[image: Empty Grid]

When I add four new objects to my underlying list, only the scrollbar changes:

[image: Scrollbar Changes]

Finally, when I press on the "down" button at the bottom of the scrollbar, the entire grid refreshes:

[image: Refreshed Grid]

Expected behaviour: The grid should refresh properly whenever the underlying database list is updated, not much later when the user tries to interact with the list.

The Xaml for my GridControl looks like this:

```
    <dxg:GridControl dxlc:DockLayoutControl.Dock="Client" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Project.TimeSeries}">

        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            ... omitted ...
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView Name="tableView1"
                           AllowEditing="False"
                           AllowColumnFiltering="True"
                           ShowAutoFilterRow="True"
                           ShowGroupPanel="False" 
                           FocusedRow="{Binding SelectedTimeSeries, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

`DataContext` of the form is set to a `TimeSeriesPresenter`:

```
public class TimeSeriesPresenter : ITimeSeriesPresenter
{
    public TimeSeriesPresenter(ITimeSeriesVisual view)
        : base(view) { ... }

    public BuilderProject Project 
        { get { ... } set { ... } }

    public TimeSeriesDefinition SelectedTimeSeries 
        { get { ... } set { ... } }
```

and a `BuilderProject` looks like this:

```
public class BuilderProject : ViewModelBase
{
    public IList<TimeSeriesDefinition> TimeSeries
    { get { ... } }
    ...
}
```

Both of these objects implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the properties are triggering the `PropertyChanged` event properly. So, everything *should* just work, right?

Clearly the DXGrid is receiving some kind of update from the view model, because the scrollbar changes. But why doesn't it repaint entirely?

Is there some kind of "mode" required for a DXGrid to do DataBinding normally?
What am I missing?

#### Update

All of my data objects inherit from `ViewModelBase` which implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. In addition to `TimeSeriesPresenter` and `BuilderProject` (shown above), here's a summary of `TimeSeriesDefinition`:

```
public class TimeSeriesDefinition : ViewModelBase
{
    public string SeriesID
    {
        get { return mSeries; }
        set { 
            if (!Equals(mSeries, value) {
                mSeries = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SeriesID");
            }
        }
    }
    ... etc ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the problem was this code:

```
public class BuilderProject : ViewModelBase
{
    public IList<TimeSeriesDefinition> TimeSeries
    { get { ... } }
    ...
}
```

Even though `IList<T>` *should* be supported, in practice its not.

The requisite fix was to change to using `ObservableCollection<T>` instead:

```
public class BuilderProject : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<TimeSeriesDefinition> TimeSeries
    { get { ... } }
    ...
}
```

In my case, this led to parallel maintenance of two lists - an underlying `IList<>` in the presentation agnostic model, and an `ObservableCollection<>` in the ViewModel. Keeping the two lists in sync is a bit of overhead, but not hard to get right.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add some additional information.  You told that the ViewModel and DataSource implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  AM I right in my assumption, that the data object does not implement this interface?  If so, I tend to think that this is the cause of this problem.
If the data object class (TimeSeriesDefinition ?) implements this interface, everything should work properly.

Also, a possible cause of this problem is that you are binding to a complex fieldName, i.e.

FieldName="Row.Text"

If this is the case, please let me know, and we will let you know how to resolve the problem.

Comment: All of the objects involved do implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, including `TimeSeriesDefinition`. I've added an update to my question to clarify this.

Comment: All of my FieldName bindings are directly to properties on the `TimeSeriesDefinition` object; but I am using a property path for my `ItemsSource` binding on the grid itself: `{Binding Project.TimeSeries}` - is this the source of my problem?

Comment: We have reviewed your code but to no avail.  It seems, everything should work properly.  Could you please create a ticked in the support center  (http://devexpress.com/support/center) and post a sample project there for the in-depth analysis?

Comment: Certainly - I'll do so Monday morning.

Comment: Case logged by email this morning (website submission wasn't working).